# Difference between kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute & kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker

Tags: ios, iphone, avaudioplayer, audiounit

I'm confused by the audio route override in the iOS, and doesn't understand the document about the difference between `kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute` & `kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker` at [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute)

So what's the difference between them? And when should we use one and the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Similarities**:

1. both work only with the play-and-record categories (`kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord`/`AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`)
2. both override the strange play-and-record choice of defaulting audio output to the super quiet, tinny little receiver (in fact the play-and-record category was designed for VOIP, where you would hold the phone up to your ear and use it like a... telephone, thus sparing you hearing damage)

**Differences**:

`kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute` is

1. older (iOS 2.1 and onwards)
2. write only, and hence slightly mysterious
3. works in the presence of a head-set, in which case setting `kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker` also changes the input to the built-in mic, ignoring the headset's mic
4. it reverts to its "default" on audio interruptions and route changes (e.g. phone calls, alarms - adding/removing audio devices). It's not clear if it reverts during a category change. If so, then that would be another similarity.

`kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker` is

1. "newer" (iOS 3.1 and onwards)
2. read/write
3. only works when no other external audio devices (e.g. a headset) are available
4. its value does not reset to default (`FALSE`) during route changes or interruptions.

Of the two, `kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute` seems about as idiosyncratic as an API can be with its bizarre side effects and surprising habit of turning itself off, so I would use `kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker`.

Of course, the C AudioSession API was deprecated in iOS 7, so you should be using the `AVAudioSession` equivalents `AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker` and `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker`.

And [QA1754](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1754/_index.html) describes the differences between these two methods in a much more accessible way than I have.